# Merging duplicated rows according to NA's in R

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, na

I have a dataset containing duplicated rows by ID, with some NAs each. I am interested to the latest observation for each ID. How can I combine them to obtain the most out of both rows (soonest and latest)?

```
df_in <-
    data.frame(A = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-02"), as.Date("2020-01-02")),
               Name = c("Adam","Adam","Rob"),
               B = c(1,2,3),
               C = c(1,2,3),
               D = c(NA,2,3))
  
  df_out <-
    data.frame(A = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-03")),
               Name = c("Adam","Rob"),
               B = c(1,3),
               C = c(1,3),
               D = c(2,3))
```

How can I ask R to pull the closest value according to a time column (merge the duplicated rows according to the variable Name) and delete the latest ??

Comment: Are you performing a forward fill or simply dropping `NA`s?

Comment: Does Name column refer to ID in your data? Why is Rob's date (A column) changing to 03?

Comment: @NelsonGon forward fill because there would be NAs in both columns more often than not and it would make me loose both rows. 

@ KarthikS Yes sorry, it should not be relevant Rob's situation. I just want to make clear that I want to merge different dates (as close as possible) filling the NAs of each other by grouping by ID (Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr,

```
df_in %>% arrange(-A) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you can do that with several `ifelse` commands.

```
library(dplyr)

df_solution = df_in %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(A) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(is.na(B), 
                    ifelse(!is.na(lag(B)), lag(B), lead(B)),
                    B
                    ),
         C = ifelse(is.na(C), 
                    ifelse(!is.na(lag(C)), lag(C), lead(C)),
                    C
                    ),
         D = ifelse(is.na(D), 
                    ifelse(!is.na(lag(D)), lag(D), lead(D)),
                    D
                    )
         )
```

If certain entries with the same `Name` that have NAs until the middle of the table, use `arrange(-A)` instead of `arrange(A)` or both.

However, if you have big "holes" in your data with a long series of NA, going back and forth within a cycle will be needed to remove all NA's. With this approach, there will be no consistency in filling last NAs because some will be filled with the previous value and some - with the next. If this is the case and consistency matter, this solution is not that good.

I am also not sure whether you need a unique entry for each name, but if so, you can also do

```
df_filtered = df_solution %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(A) %>%
  filter(A == min(A))
```

in case you need the earliest entry for each person.